# Problem with scrollTop - 30s should last, 29s stays at one place

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I have 7 sections on the website (#section1, #section2, ...). In #section1 I have a button #click_to_start. After clicking it, it should take me to the bottom of the website (to footer #lastFooter) using this code

```
$("#click_to_start").click(function() {
    $([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
        scrollTop: $("#lastFooter").offset().top
    }, 30000);
});
```

The movement from #section1 to the bottom of the page should last 30seconds (because there are various animations playing during the scroll).

The problem is, that when I click the button, I stay 29 seconds on #slide1 (the animations are playing very very slowly) and then the last 1second it just rushes me from #slide1 to bottom of the page.

Here is the ink to the website : http://php.soulmates.company/main.php

In my language the button is called "Klikni pre prehratie". There is also an option in menu to change to English language, but not everything is translated and it takes you to the old index.php, so it is not useful for you now sorry.

Answer (score 1):

okay code is messy 
But I think this can help you

```js
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $("#container").height() }, 30000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    
   <div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div>
    <div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div><div>content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, I tried your solution but unfortuatelly the result was the same :/

Comment: Then set time to 30001 instead of 30000. That might help 